# GAE weapp2 Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-api, webapp2

I get this error while using webapp2 user authentication. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How do I add access header before redirect ?

redirect code : 
`self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))`

CODE:

```
class Authenticate(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      user = users.get_current_user()
      cookie_value = self.request.cookies.get('user')

      if user==cookie_value and user!=None:
          self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
          self.response.write('Success')
      else:
          self.request.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
          self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect a user to the login page with an ajax request? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: The GAE web app2 documentation says to do so.[Using the users Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 def redirect(self, uri, permanent=False, abort=False, code=None,body=None)
```

and

```
def redirect(uri, permanent=False, abort=False, code=None, 
                                         body=None,request=None, response=None)
```

So, I think you should call the second one as (if you want to pass the response object):

```
return webapp2.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri),True,False,None
                                                       ,None,None,self.response)
```

Refer [Webapp2 Source Code](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2.html)

Comment: But still I get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&contin…WbQ. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://xxx.appspot.com' is therefore not allowed access.` Error .  Why?

Comment: I got a work around for my problem. I think on the client side you made an ajax call to the URL that triggered the handler in your backend code, maybe ajax('/login')? Instead of doing that, do window.location = '/login' which also triggers the handler but it won't be cross origin access.

Answer (score 0):

Before the `self.redirect` call, do

```
self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

or whatever value you wish to have for that header -- `self.redirect` by default makes a new response object, but you can change that with

```
return self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri,
                     response=self.response)
```

Comment: I still got the error. I checked the request header on the network log but didn't see 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. Probably that line of code didn't have any effect?

Comment: No , this wasn't working even after adding `self.request.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'` , I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error

Comment: the header does not show in network log . Is there another way to do this ?

Comment: Sorry, I had mixed up request and response -- edited the A now.

Comment: `TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'response'`

Comment: `TypeError: create_login_url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'response'`

Comment: self.redirect() is the one provided by RequestHandler, it by default takes self.response and self.request (and there's no way to override that). So I tried this:
    self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    self.redirect(users.create_logout_url('/'))
but still didn't see any change in the response headers.

Comment: Yes you can set self.response and self.request . redirect has 2 definitions.

Comment: right but even after I set self.response and self.request, the redirect still didn't seem to pick up the new header